# ¿Por qué esta convención de llamada a la DLL (C++) desde VBA produce el cierre de Excel?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, excel, vba

Se compilo en una DLL la siguiente función de `c++`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void __stdcall cmd(string comando) {

    system(comando.c_str());

}
```

Este es el código del llamado de la función en vba Excel:

```
   Public Declare PtrSafe Function cmd _
    Lib "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\ydl.dll" _
    (ByVal comando As String) As Variant


Sub test_YDL()

MsgBox (cmd("dir"))

End Sub
```

Al ejecutar el proceso `Sub` en VBA se abre rápidamente la consola CMD pero Excel (32bits) se cierra inmediatamente. Les agradecería si me pueden indicar si el problema esta en el código de VBA o en C++.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!